# Dependency injection issue service not registered using .NET core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am working on an application where I want to seed information through a service I want to call the service from the migration up method but it gives me an error Iseeder service is not registered although I have already registered my service in the Service Module. below is my code.

```
public partial class seedingData: Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            // Use the IServiceProvider to resolve the ISeederService
            using (var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>().BuildServiceProvider())
            {
                var seederService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISeederService>();
                seederService.SeedMenuData();
            }
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
```

Service Module

```
public static void Register(IServiceCollection service){

 service.AddScoped<ISeederService, SeederService>();

}

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        // applicatio migration 
        // Automatically apply migrations on startup
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        context.Database.Migrate();

    }
```

Comment: You're creating a `new ServiceCollection()` and you don't register anything in there, so there's simply nothing that can be resolved. Basically, you're dealing with multiple instances and one doesn't know anything about the other. Instead, a single instance of the `ServiceCollection` should be created and populated in the composition root of your project.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example

Comment: Hi,@Kamran Khan,I think you should try to  write an extension method  instead of  using dependecy injection here

Comment: @RuikaiFeng which class needs to be extended?